# Apache vs lighthttpd : different behaviours with mime type

Tags: debian, osx, apache-httpd, lighttpd

I have written an application, an automatic VPN provisioning web portal in python for Apple devices.

What bugs me is a difference in behaviour between the testing and production server; the former is using `Apache`, while the latter is using `lighthttpd`.

In `lighhttpd` the `.mobileconfig`file is opened and "executed" e.g. it opens SysPrefs automatically, while in Apache that is not happening.

I have already noticed `lighhtpd` is much more lax concerning proper `Content-Type` definitions, however the issue at hand is that Safari will load and "auto-execute" `.mobileconfig` files properly with `lighthttpd`whilst the same does not happen with `Apache`.

What further irks me it that in both servers I have defined properly the corresponding `mime.type` as in:

lighthttpd.conf

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "\.mobileconfig$" {
    setenv.add-response-header = ( "Content-Disposition" => "attachment" )
    mimetype.assign = (".mobileconfig" => "application/x-apple-aspen-config",
                    "" => "application/octet-stream")
}
```

As in Apache it is:

dovpn.conf (vhost)

```
AddType application/x-apple-aspen-config .mobileconfig
```

The first clue of a difference actually seems to stem from that `add-response-header` directive in `lighthttpd`.

In the generated HTML, I have:

`a download="profile.mobileconfig" href="../upload/8bd16b26-1473-4994-9803-8268a372cd0d.mobileconfig" type="application/octet-stream">Download automatic profile/a`

and I do an automatic download of that via Javascript

```js
//If in Safari - download via virtual link click
if (window.downloadFile.isSafari) {
    //Creating new link node.
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = sUrl;
    if (link.download !== undefined) {
        //Set HTML5 download attribute. This will prevent file from opening if supported.
        var fileName = sUrl.substring(sUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, sUrl.length);
        link.download = fileName;
    }
    //Dispatching click event.
    if (document.createEvent) {
        var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        e.initEvent('click', true, true);
        link.dispatchEvent(e);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The content of the generate page also only has as Content-Type:

```
Content-Type: text/html\n\n
```

both in Apache and lighthttpd. I sniffed over the wire, and there are no apparent changes made to Content-Type made via `lighthttpd`.

Will I be able to replicate similar functionality of `setenv.add-response-header` with Apache?

I have already tried to add to the Apache host:

```
<Files "*.mobileconfig">
      Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

and

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.mobileconfig$" change_header
Header set Content-Disposition attachment env=change_header
```

and

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.mobileconfig$" change_header
Header always add "Content-Disposition" "attachment" env=change_header
```

and

```
<Files "*.mobileconfig">
    Header append Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

I also have tried, in the actual directory, creating an `.htaccess` file with:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.mobileconfig$">
        ForceType application/octet-stream
        Header append Content-Disposition "attachment"
        Allow from all
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

and

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.mobileconfig$">
        ForceType application/octet-stream
        Header add Content-Disposition "attachment"
        Allow from all
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

In both cases, besides `attachment`, I also used `"attachment"`.

Please note mod_headers is active by default in Apache/Debian 9, and none of these alternatives worked out.

Actually, I just remembered `lighthttpd` is using HTTP, and `Apache` HTTPS. I tested it out lighthttpd with HTTPS, and it also works over HTTPS, while Apache does not.

Output of `curl -k -I  https://localhost/cgi-bin/vpn.py` in lighthttpd server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content type: text/html
Content-Length: 331
Date: Thu, 01 Jun 2017 09:03:26 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.45
```

Output of `curl -k -I  https://localhost/cgi-bin/vpn.py` in Apache server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Jun 2017 09:05:25 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Furthermore, in Apache too:

```
$curl -k -I https://localhost/download/xxx.mobileconfig
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Jun 2017 09:13:35 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 01 Jun 2017 03:08:57 GMT
ETag: "1f3b-550dd5b89d8df"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 7995
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Type: application/x-apple-aspen-config
```

Using Safari->Develop->Show web Inspector->Debugger->clicking on main page->Copy as curl only returns me "curl 'https://xxxx/cgi-bin/vpn.py' -Xnull" when pasting.

I also tried disabling `X-Frame-Options: "sameorigin"` and it made no difference (I knew it was a long shot)

Comment: In my experience `Content-Type:` is the header clients use to determine how to handle the server response, could you add the output of `curl -I URL | sort` for the two servers to your question?

Comment: @the_velour_fog I have posted the curl output, also about the .mobileconfig directory, thanks.

Comment: ah, sorry, thats not the response safari will be getting (as curl will be announcing itself as the user agent). are you familar with safari's copy as curl feature? here is an [instruction on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38963642/4668401) can you paste a (redacted if needed) post of that output? - instead of the curl, sorry

Comment: @the_velour_fog   Using Safari->Develop->Show web Inspector->Debugger->clicking on main page->Copy as curl only returns me "curl 'https://xxxx/cgi-bin/vpn.py' -Xnull" when pasting. e.g. it is not working. However I can assure you I have not configured headers changes for different user agents.

Comment: sure. what Im interested to know is what the `Content-Type` header safari is seeing. and particularly if its `application/octet-stream` (or similar). its not just the user agent, that matters in the HTTP request headers. there will be possibly a dozen or more headers safari will be sending, which could - or could not - be triggering the deviations between the different server responses. can you check the `Content-type` that the different servers are returning the in the web inspector tools?

Comment: @the_velour_fog Oddly enough, selecting "open link in new tab" to inspect it, executed it...

Comment: @the_velour_fog It seems it is ... something else. I will answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems using the `.htaccess` file solved the problem of adding to the headers the Content-Disposition.

However, the problem into replicating the functionality and the added complexity in debugging and tests --- seems to have another explanation.

It seems that both in the lastest beta and current version of the Sierra update `.mobileconfig` files were taken out of the Safari list of "safe" files for opening for security reasons.

I updated yesterday (or the day before yesterday) the MacOS at work, today at home, and I no longer can get `.mobileconfig` files on either the production or the pre-production system to open automatically.

I just update my iPhone to iOS 10.3.3 beta, and it also seems to confirm the tendency of Apple dealing as `.mobileconfig` provisioning files as potentially dangerous. Now, when clicking on such a file, you are presented with a new warning:

> This website is trying to open Settings to show you a configuration
>   profile. Do you want to allow this?
>   Ignore - Allow